Low WiFi hotspot throughput using RPi 4 and Ubuntu 24.04
I have a Raspberry Pi 4 running Ubuntu 24.04 (just installed). It has a USB WiFi dongle connected to the local (house) WiFi network. The internal (wlan0) WiFi interface is setup as a WiFi hotspot. I see low throughput (1 - 5 Mbps download, ~ 10 Mbps upload) from a phone connected to the WiFi hotspot.
The WiFi speed from the Raspberry Pi itself over the USB WiFi interface to the internet is about 35 Mbps so I expected the speed to be close to this.
I configured the USB WiFi interface (this connects back to the internet) using nmcli as shown below
sudo nmcli dev wifi connect MY_WIFI_SSID password MY_WIFI_PASSWORD ifname "wlx1cbfce7f64a3"
I configured the internal wlan0 interface to provide the WiFi hotspot as shown below
sudo nmcli dev wifi hotspot ifname wlan0 ssid MY_HOTSPOT_SSID password MY_HOTSPOT_PASSWORD
I have tried changing WiFi channels and bands in case of interference between the two WiFi interfaces. I have also tried running htop while performing a speed test from a device connected to the hotspot and it shows no increase in the RPi CPU load (load average stays less than 0.5). I've tried different internet speed test sites and tools wit the same results.
I may be wrong but it appears that the Raspberry Pi is bandwidth limiting devices connected to the WiFi hotspot.
Does anyone have any clues why the throughput from devices connected to the WiFi hotspot is low ?
Thanks
Paul

pja@rpi-server:~$ ip link show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: eth0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether dc:a6:32:6c:6b:24 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN mode DORMANT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether dc:a6:32:6c:6b:25 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: wlx1cbfce7f54a7: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP mode DORMANT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 1c:bf:ce:7f:54:a7 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

Similar with a little more info
pja@rpi-server:~$ ip a s
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether dc:a6:32:6c:6b:24 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether dc:a6:32:6c:6b:25 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: wlx1cbfce7f54a7: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 1c:bf:ce:7f:54:a7 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.139/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlx1cbfce7f54a7
       valid_lft 86331sec preferred_lft 86331sec
    inet6 fe80::f7:23f3:2a93:60d/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
pja@rpi-server:~$ 

I've tried the same thing on the latest Raspbian (12). In this case I don't see the low speed, the download speed is then about 30 Mbps.

Please [edit] your Question and show us ip link show. Do not reply via Add Comment.
